# Spring Boot: Use ThreadLocal-variable or pass parameters

Tags: java, spring

I´m wondering what is best practice with spring-boot and the already provided helper-classes that use `ThreadLocal` for saving values suche as `LocaleContextHolder` or `RequestContextHolder`.

Actually I do not really like to pass parameters such as `Request` or `Locale` through every method call and blows up the signature until it is finally used. I would rather like to hide this information-details and obtain the required information where necessary within the service. But is the `RequestContextHolder` or `LocaleContextHolder` the right thing to use then or is it bad habbit to rely on `ThreadLocal` operations? What is a recommended approach?

What problems might occur when relying on `ThreadLocal`? I read about cleaning-up is an important thing, but as this is done already by spring-boot I would assume these are safe operations.

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access request-dependent objects like `Locale` or `Request` and do not want to blow up your method's signature with additional paramters you can access them using static methods provided by `RequestContextHolder` or `LocaleContextHolder`.

Example:

```
public String getLocaleOfRequest(){
    return LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()
}
```

There is actually no need to define `ThreadLocal`s in your code for it.